# Recursive inferred object with optional values

Tags: typescript

I have a complex recursive type that defines Fields based on a specific object definition:

```
const items = [
  {
    name: "label",
    type: "string",
    defaultValue: "",
  },
  {
    name: "url",
    type: "url",
    defaultValue: "",
    required: false,
  },
] as const
```

And here's the type definition:

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;


type GenerateItems<T extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] extends { name: infer N extends string } 
    ? N 
    : never
  ]: 
    T[K] extends { subFields: infer S extends readonly any[] } 
      ? GenerateItems<S>[]
      : T[K] extends { type: infer Type extends string } 
        ? Type extends "string"
          ? string 
          : Type extends "url"
            ? string
            : Type extends "file"
              ? T[K] extends { allowedFileTypes: infer FT extends readonly string[] }
                ? FT[number]
                : never
              : never
        : never
}
```

Which is used like so:

```
type Items = ExpandRecursively<GenerateItems<typeof items>>
```

This works wonderfully well however I'm having a heck of a time determining how to efficiently infer if the resulting fields are optional based on if required: true exists in the initial object.

In the above example I'd expect:

```
const output: Items = {
  label: string,
  url?: string
};
```

I suspect it would employ Pick or Omit somehow but the syntax for representing it with this massive conditional structure is tricky.

[Helpful playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=82&ssc=5&pln=46&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOYDc%20yYAngA5nIDkVNItXZAB9uAVygAbQSK4TgVadxjAJELgBomUCAEdRwbQH5yAIwD2Z1XBCMCcCRLMB3CABMAYiogAVdhArkvHQA2gC6tpSiJp4QEq4BaJhhjAC%20uLgIZiBUyMCYFMgAvMjBeAREJOQAREQAbsC0cGDAWVWaBKwc1XJUbUwUUTFxCcFMBGUEkxWcVRJwJrF9k5OdM0H8S8vIrhDwohJgAGr2ojOby9p6BpzUp%202TKffjY1PEM%20IS5yt%201R9fBDs9gdjhJTtV-shLvptORbhAnshHi8JstptVgBg4LR-BDVt15GAIQNosBYvFyKMtpMUVTCG9uvNFgiqXjkFV1rQIctAXB9kcTmdmVsoddYVA7i9lkjaThJVs0WzgJkQFzvl02cpVKq7A5nG5PKpfBwRlU2Bt1GyKLVOaEhQRpVtbS8HU6UqFkHACsqqOlcKtkABRAAebGsrgAShAEOIKMBarEWAAebwAPiKyG8yAgQcgIHiyDMJgAVlGwExDBmszmIHmCqAYNBkAB5ZAV7AlADSuRAyAA1hAWGYYM3QuRg6G85Ho1BY-GJEmm8EO6E0ylkOQQBB41AmORvIx0v6AOI16BNCDoCAYCjJqu5-PaOCuLLzj0gFhhNPFCZL7t9gdDpWABkyAAAYACTYCYDSgGAKSgR6BTeEu7rZveBTtgq9aNgAcneNb5hyiLIC8FZ4S8G5btATCjiRyzIcu%20G1jgkQkmSCTYVAyAAMpMQ%20EBPi%20LBvh%207prnKFYnpuUDnpe16JtxKZhHKe4oXxGHMD83YNlxRooGhBEFER4kyhWenqZa1B0FUcrLBWRG2ZMe5%20BZVR-I5dmUFZ-AeU5GYuQZzFVJqEA2TKVJmWpgX5u29iOC4HheHpHEgDpyDuJm0UFI%20z4gK%20HJhIivkRelyEgKIGALFAoTFVslHbrVBD1dRMrNTuaR%20i5ckFMU45hlOMZxgmiZSWekDdYmqyAXkV4UCmKbpAA9ItmkcIks3pngy3ynA9SNM0WTkFtK0ynMCwSIE3kMLg20yh8l18Ndt20hiWL%20EdN0neFBBnbED10Iwz3fUqh1smanLCJa1pVIDX1UikySfVsCPhEjKRAA)

Comment: So something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvABnm)?

Comment: Hmmm interested composition approach. Not quite there though. It results in: type Items = {
    navigation?: {
        images?: {
            icon?: "png" | "svg" | undefined;
            label: string;
        }[] | undefined;
        label: string;
        url: string;
    }[] | undefined;
}

Comment: What's the desired outcome?

Comment: type Items = {
  label: string,
  url?: string
};

Comment: I don't understand. Your playground has a much more complicated input...

Comment: Yeah, sorry I confused myself. It works in both flat and recursive scenarios: https://shorturl.at/bDKNV if you post as a comment I'll accept the answer. And thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first move the logic to another type, as this logic will be needed for both optional and required fields:

```
type GenerateField<T> = T extends { subFields: infer S extends readonly any[] } 
      ? GenerateItems<S>[]
      : T extends { type: infer Type extends string } 
        ? Type extends "string"
          ? string 
          : Type extends "url"
            ? string
            : Type extends "file"
              ? T extends { allowedFileTypes: infer FT extends readonly string[] }
                ? FT[number]
                : never
              : never
        : never
```

Then we can change your existing `GenerateItems` type to treat fields with `require: true` differently by adding it onto `extends { name: infer N ... }`:

```
type GenerateItems<T extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] extends { name: infer N extends string; require?: false } 
    ? N 
    : never
  ]?: GenerateField<T[K]>
} & {
  [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] extends { name: infer N extends string; require: true } 
    ? N 
    : never
  ]: GenerateField<T[K]>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOYDc+yYAngA5nIDkVNItXZAB9uAVygAbQSK4TgVadxjAJELgBomUCAEdRwbQH5yAIwD2Z1XBCMCcCRLMB3CABMAYiogAVdhArkvHQA2gC6tpSiJp4QEq4BaJhhjAC+uLgIZiBUyMCYFMgAvMjBeAREJOQAREQAbsC0cGDAWVWaBKwc1XJUbUwUUTFxCcFMBGUEkxWcVRJwJrF9k5OdM0H8S8vIrhDwohJgAGr2ojOby9p6BpzUp+2TKffjY1PEM+IS5yt+1R9fBDs9gdjhJTtV-shLvptORbhAnshHi8JstptVgBg4LR-BDVt15GAIQNosBYvFyKMtpMUVTCG9uvNFgiqXjkFV1rQIctAXB9kcTmdmVsoddYVA7i9lkjaThJVs0WzgJkQFzvl02cpVKq7A5nG5PKpfBwRlU2Bt1GyKLVOaEhQRpVtbS8HU6UqFkHACsqqOlcKtkABRAAebGsrgAShAEOIKMBarEWAAebwAPiKyG8yAgQcgIHiyDMJgAVlGwExDBmszmIHmCqAYNBkAB5ZAV7AlADSuRAyAA1hAWGYYM3QuRg6G85Ho1BY-GJEmm8EO6E0ylkOQQBB41AmORvIw-X5kABxGvQJoQIauZNp4qZ7O5-Pt4lXhL1xsAZSrj4K2jgriyecPRAFgwkRZA5QrU9NygC90AgDAKETD8UzCOU92-Gsn2YH5uwbKAMyPB8sIKDlwLlAgKyNFBiNrS1qDoKoKMmCsyOYgg9yI6s6KqP52JYygGP4fiOMIjhMJ4zUICYmUqSoiTsPsRwXA8LxqLfEB8OQdx724-M-wAkAgI5MC0lk2kKx04IQFEDAFigUIRK2Dct2gJzRM3bdmJcrzD3E6Dz0geDEOTBTfwgf9AJYYDQJXdMJiXbs+wHIdKwAMmQAADAASbATAaUAwBSTKPQKbwl3dWjsIVd8CIAOTCwS+AYSFdGhCBjGQeAJAoFA1xeCsGpeHy3IIUJOoC2DICvZMKpTXA1wyhKu1AZLB2HTMMpyvKCvAYrSozCrGvbGrNMbBqqtIoSWpFGFmHFPqIOWQansmEadzG8hJovGbyuXea0j8lBgoKYpxzDKcYzjBNE2+oL8kTVZUryBCKBTebcAAekxnDxJB+KsZx1E4HqRpmiycg8Gx2S5gWCRAmuxhqZlD4GeapmidpDEsX8SnCfMyZadiNm6A5gWCCVCm2TNTlhEta0qjFmUUmSfmpVV6mUiAA)

Comment: Thank you! I was too focused on trying to get the required values in the same block that I hadn't thought past composing the types further.